# Problem with Page layouts creation in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi I am trying to brand my site in sharepoint 2013.

I have created a html page layout and uploaded it in the master page gallery and tried converting it.

It says convertion is successful.

when I create a page with this page layout and check it none of my changes are reflected.

I have seen couple of problems similar to this in this forum but couldn't find a solution.

I wanna know what is that something, that I am missing probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know lately that unlike master pages we cant convert a html to page layout.
so i tried creting a page layout using design manager. two files one html and one aspx are created.
and i started editing the html page accordingly with necessary markup which gave me my result

Comment: Don't add signatures in your answer, your profile badge (User Flair) contains your name and it can take to your profile for further details.. Plus since you have answered your own question, please mark it as answer to close the Question..

Comment: And I'm not criticizing every other thing you do :).. you are most welcome to answer the questions!